# Android firebase query equivalence

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android app I need to compare equivalence of two Firebase database query objects. Is there some way for me to assert that two query objects are equivalent based on their database references and query parameters?

The Javascript Firebase version of the Query class has an isEqual() method which produces the desired behaviour. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

I tried the following equivalence test in my Android code but this does not produce expected behaviour:

```
Reference ref = Firebase.getInstance();
String child = "childKey"; //this is a valid child of ref
Query query1 = ref.child(child).limitTo(10);
Query query2 = ref.child(child).limitTo(10);
query1 == query2 //false
query1.equals(query2) //false
```

Comment: Have you tried `orderByChild(child).equalsTo(whatever)`? Or I think you should get both data and compare them when they both completely acquired.

Comment: I'd like to assert equals on the Query objects and not the data that they contain. By doing this I can avoid unnessary network calls.

Comment: My apologies the previous question was ambigous. I have since updated it.

Comment: Hi, Doug from the Firebase team here.  This is actually a known issue with Query's implementation of equals().  I was active in a proposal to get this working the way you want, but it was determined that it's actually a breaking API change, which means it's unfortunately a difficult issue to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
query1.zzWM().toString.equals(query2.zzWM().toString) // true
```

I don't think you'd need this though. For as far as I know Firebase keeps the results cached for as long as there is a listener on a reference. So even if you would have 2 it would just get it from the cached version, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks this works. The string returned contains the database path as well as the query parameters. Precisely what I was looking for. Hacky approach but it will do the job.

query.zzVd().toString() in the version of Firebase SDK I am using.

Comment: This could possibly break in the future, as that zzWM method name has been obfuscated by proguard and is not guaranteed to be the same at every release.